# Change TextInputLayout hint text after focused

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-textinputlayout

In a fragment, I would like to change the TextInputLayout hint text after the user touches the TextInputEditText.  Before it animates up to the floating hint.

I can change the hint no problem, but I want the user to touch it first, then change it.

How can I do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change hint text color Use `View.OnFocusChangeListener` to set the `hintTextAppearance`. Try the config below.

```
 <style name="inactive" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/darker_gray</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/darker_gray</item>
</style>

<style name="active" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
</style>
```

XMl

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/tet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/et"
    app:hintTextAppearance="@style/inactive"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    app:hintEnabled="true">
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/edit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Floating Hint" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Change the style during focus change.

```
final TextInputLayout inputLayout=findViewById(R.id.tet);
    final TextInputEditText edit=findViewById(R.id.edit);
    edit.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(hasFocus)
                inputLayout.setHintTextAppearance(R.style.active);
            else
                inputLayout.setHintTextAppearance(R.style.inactive);
        }
    });
```

**EDIT**:- To change Hint text only you can just change it on focus change.

```
edit.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(hasFocus)
                edit.setHint("Enter name");
            else
                edit.setHint("Name");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you.  My problem was I was using the TextInputLayout Instead of the TextInputEditText.  The TextInputLayout could change the hint but the onFocusChange method did not work.

Comment: using this solution will prevent the keyboard to show tho', as setting the hint will hide the keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

You could use OnFocusChangedListener and retrieve the event that user has the EditText's focus.

```
myEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (hasFocus) {
                     // do what you have to do
                }

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way..

```
     editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
            editText.setHint("Please Enter Name"); // here set new hint
        }
    });
```